# r - dedupe the rows with value in dataframe

Tags: r, duplicates

How to subset only the rows with values in a particular column among the duplicates based on another column.

Example:

```
df

A B  C D 
1 NA 8 7
1 5  8 9
2 6  5 8
2 NA 5 6
3 NA  8 5
```

So in the above dataset, first 4 rows are duplicate based on column A and C, so among them, I want to choose only the rows which has value in column B.

Desired output,

```
A B C D
1 5 8 9
2 6 5 8
3 NA 8 5
```

Thanks.

Comment: What if there are more than one rows you can select? What would be the rule?

Comment: Select both with values in column B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```
df <- read.table(text="A B  C D 
1 NA 8 7
1 5  8 9
2 6  5 8
2 NA 5 6
3 NA  8 5", header=T)


df %>% 
  group_by(A,C) %>% 
  filter(n()==1|!is.na(B))

      A     B     C     D
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     8     9
2     2     6     5     8
3     3    NA     8     5
```

Answer (score 4):

Duplicates back or forwards and not missing on `B`; or not a duplicate:

```
anydup <- duplicated(df[c("A","C")]) | duplicated(df[c("A","C")], fromLast=TRUE)
df[(anydup & (!is.na(df$B))) | (!anydup),]

#  A  B C D
#2 1  5 8 9
#3 2  6 5 8
#5 3 NA 8 5
```

Or use `ave` to check the length per group as per @HubertL's dplyr answer:

```
df[!is.na(df$B) | ave(df$B, df[c("A","C")], FUN=length)==1,]
#  A  B C D
#2 1  5 8 9
#3 2  6 5 8
#5 3 NA 8 5
```

Comment: That `ave()` method scratches me right where I itch.

Comment: Haha, of course!  It's also a Seinfeld reference :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[.N==1 | complete.cases(B)] , .(A, C)]$V1]
#    A  B C D
#1: 1  5 8 9
#2: 2  6 5 8
#3: 3 NA 8 5
```